# Installing apps with apple configurator 2 - unable to install error

Tags: ios, xcode, apple-configurator

I'm trying to use apple configurator 2 to create a blueprint of my app to install on a group of 10 ipads.  I have a valid developer & distribution certificate.  I can install the apps via xcode just fine.  The archive I made with xcode is visible to configurator but when added to a blueprint and applied to an ipad the app icon appears darker and when clicked I get an "Unable to Install" error.

I also signed up for simplemdm trial.  Getting some weird errors.

```
Failed to create session info: Failed to retrieve session info. ({
FunctionName = "init_lockdown_server_block_invoke_7";
NSLocalizedDescription = "Failed to retrieve session info.";
NSUnderlyingError = "Error Domain=com.apple.MobileActivation.ErrorDomain Code=-2 \"Failed to copy ingest data.\" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x10152a860 {Error Domain=com.apple.MobileActivation.ErrorDomain Code=-2 \"Failed to retrieve IMEI.\" UserInfo={SourceLine=455, NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to retrieve IMEI., FunctionName=-[MACollectionInterface copyIngestData:]}}, SourceLine=678, FunctionName=-[MobileActivationDaemon createTunnel1SessionInfoWithCompletionBlock:]_block_invoke, NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to copy ingest data.}";
SourceLine = 271;
}) [com.apple.MobileActivation.ErrorDomain – 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE (-2) [sys = 0x3F, sub = 0xFFF, code = 0x3FFE (16382)]]
```

Do I have to manually add each device to my distribution cert to get app to work with configurator?  Shouldn't the simplemdm be doing that bit for me?

Comment: Looks like certificate signed issue. How you sign your app?

Comment: i used adhoc with my distribution certificate

Comment: If you use adhoc you need to add devices to your certificate

Comment: Is there another way to add devices to certificates other than by installing the app on them with xcode?

Comment: Apple Developer Portal

Comment: I have to register the devices with an MDM and the developer portal.  I thought part of the point of the MDM & configurator was so my developer account didn't have to use its 100 device slots on deployments?  Such a simple process.

Comment: When you creating Adhoc cert on apple dev portal you have to add devices you want to use this cert https://support.magplus.com/hc/en-us/articles/204270188-iOS-Creating-an-Ad-Hoc-Distribution-Provisioning-Profile

Comment: Or just use Universal Distribution certificate, why you need adhoc cert?

Comment: You have 100 device slots because your account not for enterprise

Comment: currently trying to get enterprise ... our employee count is 102

Comment: If you need to install your app for all 102 users, use distribution certificate. adhoc use for testing(like you upload your app to company app store and you want to launch your app only on some devices)

Comment: You can now sell "B2B" custom apps to yourself. Enrol your organisation in Apple Business Manager and use a custom B2B app via AppStore Connect. You will end up with an App Store signed app that you can install on any device that is only available to your own organisation. This is better than enterprise apps as the provisioning profile and signing certs never expire.  There is a 2019 WWDC talk on app distribution that will give you helpful information

Comment: I watched the WWDC video, thanks for the tip on that.  It seems like In-House distribution is the right solution for us, but that we will be forced to use the Custom App method since we have not been granted the enterprise developer license.

Comment: As I currently understand this process, to distribute the app, I have to do this thru a regular developer certificate.  I must register the app in app store connect, requires me to attach my ssn, tax status, and bank account to my developer cert, fill out tax documents, and set myself as 5 different business contacts.  Next, I enroll my company in Apple Business Manager, so I can get an id code for the business with which I can restrict distribution of my app to my organization.  I have to then add all the devices we have to an MDM account as well as the Apple Business Manager account.

Comment: For Certificate or Signature issue you get: `init_lockdown_server_block_invoke_5` the issue you have `init_lockdown_server_block_invoke_7` is not same.